# perl code for comparing file contents

Tags: perl, wildcard, string-comparison

I'm a newbie in perl scripting. I have 2 files. I want to compare contents line by line and delete the matching ones. if i use a wild card in 1 file to match multiple lines in second file, it should delete multiple matches and write the rest to another file. I got a bit from another mail it does not take care of wild cards

```
use strict;
use warnings;
$\="\n";

open my $FILE, "<", "file.txt" or die "Can't open file.txt: $!";
my %Set = map {$_ => undef} <$FILE>;
open my $FORBIDDEN, "<", "forbidden.txt" or die "Can't open forbidden.txt: $!";
my %Forbidden = map {$_ => undef} <$FORBIDDEN>;
open my $OUT, '>', 'output' or die $!;
my %Result = %Set; # make a copy
delete $Result{$_} for keys %Forbidden;
print $OUT keys %Result
```

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1163469

Comment: Are you trying to have `forbidden.txt` provide you with exclusion patterns? Or must the contents of this file be applied in order? It looks a little bit like a task for `grep`.

Comment: What do you mean by "wild cards"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with "wild card".

Nevertheless there are many ways to do what you want. Since it's prettier to use some existing modules you can use the [List::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/~jkeenan/List-Compare-0.53/lib/List/Compare.pm) module available at cpan.

With the following code you use this module to store all the lines contained in the one file (file.txt) but not in the other file (forbidden.txt). So you implicitly **match** the lines which are equal. This code **doesn't delete** them from the file, but find them.

Your code would look like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp qw(read_file); #cpan-module
use List::Compare; #cpan-module

chomp( my @a_file = read_file 'file.txt' );
chomp( my @b_file = read_file 'forbidden.txt' );

#here it stores all the lines contained in the 'file.txt' 
#but not in the 'forbidden.txt' in an array 
my @a_file_only = List::Compare->new( \@a_file, \@b_file )->get_Lonly;

print "$_\n" for @a_file_only; 
#here you could write these lines in a new file to store them. 
#At this point I just print them out.
```

the new approach:

```
foreach my $filter (@b_file){
    @a_file = grep{ /${filter}/} @a_file;
}
 print Dumper(@a_file);
```

It will reduce the lines in the @a_file step by step by using each filter.

Comment: >what I need to do is file1.txt 
E: not matching signals (<file path>; line no .*)
file2.txt
 E: not matching signals (<file path>; line no 1)
 E: not matching signals (<file path>; line no 63)
 E: too lengthy names    (<file path>; line no 354>)
output expected file3.txt
E: too lengthy names    (<file path>; line no 354>)
.* shld be able to match 2 scenarios in file2.txt

Comment: Is there any other way I can say to ignore the string line no and do pattern matching or edit file1.txt to do the multiple matching. I need to filter out the non matching ones

Comment: well, I also have an error in my solution. Th File::Slurp isn't a core module, so you have to downlaod and install it from cpan.

Try this first, if it apperas to be the same issue I wil have another look!

Comment: Hm, I don't catch what you want. If you want the non-mathing lines from these two files you can use my code from above, maybe extended with the ->get_Ronly to find the other non-matching lines. Or just use the symmetric difference ->get_symmetric_difference()

Comment: yes I need the non-matching lines but with a condition. My work scenario is that one of the files is like a filter file. Lines from second file need to be filtered out as per filter file. I wanted to reduce lines of code of filter file so I add ".* " to match multiple lines with same strings in the work file but some values in the line will be different. so i need perl to match 1 line of the filter file to multiple lines of work file.meanwhile I will download file::slurp and check the provided solution

Comment: Now i got it!

if each line in the filter.txt represents a string you want to match in the bigFile.txt you can do the following:

split up each file into lines:
foreach filterLine do:
`@filteredLines = grep{ /yourFilterString/} @bigFileLines`
`push(@result, @filteredLines)`